# Expand an seq into individual scalars

Tags: dictionary, clojure, seq

I want to feed the members of a lazy seq produced by map as individual arguments to another function. Is there a function that splices a (lazy) seq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [apply](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply).

```
(defn f [a b c d e]
  (str "a = " a " b = " b " c = " c " d = " d " e = " e))

(println (apply f (range 5)))

;; prints: a = 0 b = 1 c = 2 d = 3 e = 4
```

As you can see, function f takes 5 arguments and (range 5) returns a lazy seq of 5 arguments.

Just make sure the size of the seq is the same as the amount of arguments expected by the function, or you will get an exception at runtime.

Comment: So simple after all. I'm trying to apply (pun intended) my neurons into digesting functional-style programming but keep finding myself thinking dirty ol' procedural tricks. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, in case you want to mention this at a party, the term for what Leonel showed you is "destructuring".

Comment: I thought destructuring had to do with slicing a data structure and creating bindings for its various fields inside a scope, not just assigning names to arguments.

Comment: Oh sorry you're right.  When I read the example, I thought of something else.

Comment: +1 for the nice example. Also worth noting that apply will force evaluation of the entire lazy seq in the context of the original question.